# How to keep the header comments up to date in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, comments

Xcode has a habit of putting all kinds of (redundant) information at the top of each code file it creates, containing copyright notices, class names, project names and client names. Like it or not, once you create a new class "A", then refactor it to be called "B", the information is wrong already. The comments will keep saying that this is "A.h" or "A.m". In addition, if you reuse classes from one project in a next, it will also state the wrong project name.

```
//
//  A.h
//  ProjectName
//
//  Created by Author on 19-06-11.
//  Copyright 2011 CompanyName. All rights reserved.
//
```

There must be a reason there aren't many people complaining about this. What is your trick to keep the header comments up to date? Is there a tool that auto-corrects it all? Is there a hidden setting?

Cheers,
EP.

Comment: There are file templates which are filled with the above shown comments at class file creation time. I would doubt that xcode has a way of keeping this up to date, but I'm not absolutely sure...

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that the comments will lose their accuracy very quickly, no matter what you put in the templates. Xcode doesn't refactor comments or anything. How do people keep the comments in sync?

Comment: I think most people just remove those useless comments. At least me, and both companies I've worked for :) And if you REALLY need those, I think a simple script would do the trick : just parse your project files, find the comment and update it as you need (using python, regexp and such, it's not really difficult)

Comment: agree: those comments are not there to stay. Why should I comment in each source code file what the file's name is, and what project it was created for? The relevant part is the Copyright, everything else has to go.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There may be a way to update your comments but it will be tricky.

As far a customizing the template, this is not as bad. it is just a text file located in 
`/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/File Templates/Cocoa Touch/`

Don't edit the files here, they will get overwritten when you update, or reinstall xcode.
Place your custom templates here, in your home directory.

`~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/File Templates/`

[High Order Bit explains further](http://blog.highorderbit.com/2009/03/15/customizing-xcode-cocoa-touch-file-templates/).

Comment: This indeed looks like the solution that makes most sense. If only my Xcode wouldn't crash when I try to instantiate a class from my own template, even if it's an exact copy of the ones in the regular Cocoa Touch Classes.

Comment: @epologee hmmm, the only mac i have is at work, ill take a look on monday.

Comment: @epologee i am still on 3.2.8, and can't update just yet. I'll try but can't promise.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the template system got a complete overhaul in 4.x, whatever templates you have will need some severe modification before you port them over.

Answer (score 4):

**Short Answer:** Use SCM Commit Hooks ([git example](http://book.git-scm.com/5_git_hooks.html), [svn example](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch05s02.html), [cvs example](http://pragmaticautomation.com/cgi-bin/pragauto.cgi/Monitor/LettingCVSPullTheTrigger.rdoc/style/print))

**Reason**: Well, you can be rest assured that XCode will not do it. What XCode can do is attach itself to version control system.  Its fairly simple to do using commit hooks that most SCMs support. They fire up before/after the commit/push so that source code is updated. You can even send automated emails when commiting etc.

Since GIT is the most popular one in my opinion these days, see [this article](http://progit.org/book/ch7-3.html).

Comment: I like the suggestion, but just linking to the commit hook references doesn't cut it for me. Do you have a working script?

Comment: See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/thinkupapp/viGDvVHShwA
They have  good example for, for example writing a license agreement on top. You can obviously add more things as well.

Answer (score 0):

I use custom templates (see @TMB's comment for a link explaining creating your own) that eliminate the project name and copyright info. File name changes rarely enough that that hasn't bothered me yet. If it became a problem, I would just eliminate it from my templates. If I did it again, I would eliminate the file line from the start: There are better and more reliable ways to figure out what file you're in than going to the top of the file.