# Xcode: Ensure correct filename in header comments?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, comments

Is there a quick fix/check to ensure that filenames in header comments actually matches the filename?

I've just done a huge refactoring / convention changes and found that some I've forgotten to update header comments for some files.

I'm aware of [this other question about header comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791453/how-to-keep-the-header-comments-up-to-date-in-xcode). But I don't want to change any templates. I *like* the template Xcode give me as it is. I just want to make sure it matches.

---

#### Example

```
//
//  XXShim.h
//  ProjectX
//
//  Created by Me Myself on 3/15/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 My Company Ltd. All rights reserved.
//

#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface YYProxy : NSObject
```

See, the `XXShim` is now the `YYProxy` in a file now called `YYProxy.h` but the header comment is still wrong.

Comment: you can go for script, write a script to get the name of file and search the same name in that file itself, if it return false then it means names are not same.

Answer (score 0):

I put together [a one-liner](https://gist.github.com/frankus/5ce28924819a812a2035) that will at least help you locate them.

```
find . -iname "*.[mh]" -exec sed -n "2s|^//  ||p" "{}" \; -exec basename "{}" \; | uniq -u
```

You'll need to open a Terminal window and `cd` to the root of your project. You'll get pairs of lines with the filename in the comment printed above the actual filename in instances where they don't match.

EDIT: This script (make sure you've got a backup) should actually update every file's second line to the correct comment:

```
find . -iname '*.[mh]' -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do basename=`basename "$file"`; sed -i '' "2s|//  .*\$|//  $basename|" "$file"; done
```